# How many maximum classes can be recognized using VGGNet-16?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I have 200 classes to recognize.

I prepare 600 images for each class and I have 120,000 number of images prepared to train.

I am thinking to use VGGNet-16. Would it be possible to recognize such number of classes using VGGNet-16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VGG was mainly developed and benchmarked on the ILSVRC classification task, where the task is to classify images into one of 1000 categories.

So yes, 200 should be perfectly fine.